# open Iframe in current page with a link

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I am trying to get a link to open a iframe on the current page. Also I do not want the Iframe to be visable untill the user selects the link.

Currently I have this code but the i frame is is visable on the page and has a error.

```
Response.Write ("<a href=""form.asp?Int=" & recordsetAddressBook("Int") & "target=frame1"">")

<iframe name="FRAME1" width="730" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Please help!

Comment: It's good that you don't tell us *what* error you are getting. This way, everyone gets to guess. :)

Comment: lol! I get a 404 error but this does not make much sense because it is a local file and the link works if the iframe is not involved. any ideas?

Comment: The "target" value seems to be inside the URL. That might be the problem

Comment: "Response.Write ("<a href=""form.asp?Int=" & recordsetAddressBook("Int") & """target=frame1"">")"

this now opens the link in another tab but the error is gone :) iframe is empty as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the basic formatting of your Response.Write.

```
Response.Write ("<a href=""form.asp?Int=" & recordsetAddressBook("Int") & """ target=""frame1"">")
```

Comment: Thank You Erick! The link is now opening in the iframe. Any ideas on how I can hide the iframe until the link is selected?